# Electron + Ionic + child_process

Tags: ionic-framework, webpack, electron, child-process

I'm building an electron app to run on Windows to move a robot. (The controlling device must be windows as requested by the customer) It's built in Ionic with typescript and I'm attempting to create a desktop solution with a feature that runs some .exe files to move the robot in some predefined movements. They are a group of .exe files made by another guy, and they work fine when run from the shell. Those exe files do turn off/on lights, move an arm, etc... Right now those exe files work and they are all in a C:\botcontrol\ folder.

I've been struggling with node's `child_process` to be able to run all those exe files from a simple interface. My problem is that I'm not able to include `child_process` in any manner without getting the console error `t(...).execFile is not a function`.

I've been digging two days through the internet in various languages on how to include the `child_process` node module in a typescript angular 7 app, but I'm really stuck with this and I don't know how to solve it without getting the cursed error above. I tried adding to tsconfig:

```
  "map": {
    "child_process": "@node/child_process"
  }
```

and many other webpack config attempts, but none of them worked for me.

Right now what I need is to add 'child_process' so when I run a service I can import it like:

```
import { exec,execFile} from "child_process";
...
```

or

```
import * as cp from "child_process";
...
```

I read somehwere that I need to add the module to be exported at SystemJS, or at the webpack config, but I don't find any config like that in my project.

My dependencies are these in the package.json:

```
...
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "~8.1.2",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.14.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.14.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.14.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.9.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^3.3.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "electron-json-storage": "^4.1.8",
    "ng-connection-service": "^1.0.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
    "simple-keyboard": "^2.26.4",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "wine": "^0.9.8",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.801.2",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.801.2",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.1.2",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "~2.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^8.10.54",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.1",
    "electron": "^6.0.10",
    "electron-installer-dmg": "^3.0.0",
    "electron-packager": "^14.0.6",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3"
  },
...
```

Can anyone help me, please? It would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 6):

If you're using the `@capacitor-community/electron` platform to build your app you must consider the following:

- Electron works with two process types, the **main process** and the **renderer process** (find more info [here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/process-model))
- The renderer process is basically a web browser, that **cannot** use native capabilities such as `child_process` while the main process can
- The renderer process **can** communicate with the main process, more info [here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrendererinvokechannel-args)
- Your ionic/angular app is built to run as a renderer process

## A possible solution:

Send a message from the renderer process (angular) to the main process (electron) in order to make the main process run the executable file and get back the output to the renderer process (aka black magic).

*How?*

### Create the main process handler

Modify the file `YOUR_PROJECT_DIR/electron/src/index.ts`

add the import:

```
import {ipcMain} from 'electron';
import {execFileSync} from 'child_process';
```

add the event handler at the and of the file:

```
ipcMain.handle('execCommand', (event, arg) => {
  //this will handle an event called 'execCommand' triggered from the renderer process
  let cmdRes = execFileSync("./path-to-file.exe", [], {encoding: 'utf8'});
  //cmdRes contains the file execution output
  return cmdRes;
});
```

### Expose `ipcRenderer` to the main context of the ionic/angular application

Modify the file `YOUR_PROJECT_DIR/electron/src/preload.ts`

add this:

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electron', {
  ipc: { ...ipcRenderer }
});
```

**A security concern**: a user could open the developer tools and modify the javascript code to invoke events with malicious content, it's not a real problem in a local environment but it could be with remote resources.

### Communicate with the main process from the angular app

Let's say you're inside a ionic/angular page:

```
callExecutable() {
    (<any>window).electron.ipc.invoke('execCommand').then(
      res=>console.log(res) //res contains the command output from the main process
    );
}
```

In this way you can create an event handler for each `.exe` files you have to call and create an angular service to `.invoke()` each handler.

Just tested and it's working with `ionic` version `6.18.1` and `@capacitor-community/electron` version `7.5.6`

Comment: Welcome to the Stack Overflow community, Roberto. This is a useful first answer, with an admirable level of detail. Keep up the good work.

Comment: @JeremyCaney thank you! After all these years, it's great to be the one who answers for the first time.

Comment: This answer is great! It would really deserve more upvotes and it would deserve the answer status. If the questionner has really spent two days searching around, it could/should have accepted this answer!